# Output of the below C Code

Tags: c, logical-operators

```
int i=-1,j=-1,k=0,l=2,m;
m=l++||i++ && j++ && k++;
printf("%d %d %d %d %d",i,j,k,l,m);
```

Output of the code is: `-1 -1 0 3 -1`

My question is why `i++` `j++` and `k++` is not being evaluated even when `&&` has a higher priority over `||` ?

Comment: "even when" is "because."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See
[Short-circuit evaluation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Essentially what's happening is that as l++=3 which is not 0, it evaluates to True (only 0 would be False).  Thus, the second part of the expression after || is not evaluated.

Comment: Does it mean that in case of Short circuit eval priority of the operators are ignored?

Comment: You state `l++=3`? This is post increment, thus `l++=2` I guess?

Comment: The question linked above actually goes into detail about [sequence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).  In this case, this means that the first part before || gets completely evaluated before the second part (so l would be considered 3 before the ||); it takes priority over the operator precedence.  I think reading the wikipedia article and the other q&a linked would help further explain.

Answer (score 1):

Think

```
m=l++||i++ && j++ && k++;
```

as

```
m = ( (l++)|| ( (i++ && j++) && (k++) ) );
```

As you know `&&` has higher operator precedence, therefore `i++ && j++ && k++` will be grouped as `(i++ && j++) && k++` and then `( (i++ && j++) && (k++) )`.
Because of the short-circuit behavior of `||`, after evaluating `l++`, which is `true` and therefore the right operand ( (i++ && j++) && (k++) ) of `||` is not evaluated.